# Do I need to make any changes in my node.js codes to deploy it over the web?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, web-hosting, vs-web-site-project

I've created a website using html,css,sass,js, node, express & ejs. Do I need to make any changes in the code to deploy it over the web?
P.S. I've set the port to process.env thing and added the css & js files to a public folder. Are there any other changes I need to make?

Comment: You need to deploy your code to heroku or any cloud service like AWS in order to access from internet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking.

You basically need to make it publicly available.

You could either do it using a host provider or in theory you could set up your own server using apache ,nginx etc then reroute your home router to your machine (laptop).

Your server will run the same way as locally in theory.
You just need something to redirect the traffic in and out.